# Global push notification service

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am building a hybrid which needs to be released across globe including china. I have started development with GCM and later came to know that GCM won't work in china. I have two questions

1. Like china is there any other country that GCM won't work ?
2. If not GCM, which is best push notification services which will work in china as well as outside china ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Pushy (https://pushy.me/) works worldwide (incl. China) and is completely independent of GCM/FCM. It's also easy to migrate from GCM. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I don't think any other country except China has banned it completely although some Arab countries have their own reason for blocking or banning some of Google's products.

Google restricts access to some of its business services (like YouTube, Gmail, Blogger, Maps) in certain countries or regions, such as Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, Syria, Pakistan and almost all Arab countries.

[image: Google Transparency Report] Screenshot from [here](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/disruptions/#group=REGION)

For your second question, from AWS [SNS ( Simple Notification Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/),

> SNS Mobile Push lets you use Simple Notification Service (SNS) to
>   deliver push notifications to Apple, Google, Fire OS, and Windows
>   devices, as well as Android devices in China with Baidu Cloud Push.

Comment: Is SNS are wrapper to GCM and APNS ? Read from some forum. But in china it uses baidu to deliver the push notifications ?